# Evolution Email Set tup

Tags: outlook

As I start to learn Linux, I am migrating my email account from Outlook to Evolution mail on Ubuntu. I am not able to set the "Exchange Web Services" settings correctly when setting up my company email. Where can I find my current incoming server settings in Outlook?

I checked the FILE -> Account Settings -> E-mail tab and saw my account type is Microsoft Exchange, but not more information about the server address. Does anyone know where can I find it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just double click the line which shows the account type, then you should see the server settings.